# RoR - index method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm getting this error for the URL http://localhost:3000/dashboard/

`Routing Error No route matches "/dashboard"`

but http://localhost:3000/dashboard/index works correct

How can i make all the below URLs works and shows the same view `views/dashboard/index.html.erb`

```
http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/dashboard
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/index
```

My routes file is

```
Mytest::Application.routes.draw do
  get "dashboard/index"
  root :to => "dashboard#index"
end
```

My controller file is

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Mytest::Application.routes.draw do
  match "/dashboard", :to => 'dashboard#index'
  root :to => "dashboard#index"
end
```

You can also add generic routes of `/:controller/:action/:id(.:format)` style.

Comment: When I added `map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'` I got the following error on starting the rails server with `rails server'    <code>/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined
 local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x3a2b7a8>
 (NameError)
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dis
patch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `instance_exec'
        from E:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dis
patch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in `draw' </code>

Comment: that's because you used old (rails 2.x routing api). There's no block variable anymore. Just add this line into the block: `match ':controller/:action/:id(.:format)'`. More information can be found in rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
  map.root :controller => "dashboard", :action => "index"
  map.dashboard "/dashboard", :controller => "dashboard", :action => "index"
  map.connect "/dashboard/:action", :controller => "dashboard", :action => "index"
  #standard routes
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Or you could make it more standard

```
  #special case
  map.root :controller => "dashboard", :action => "index"

  #general case
  map.connect ":controller", :action => "index"
  map.connect ":controller/:action"

  #standard routes
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Comment: This API is not rails3 style.

Comment: I've not used rails 3, but why not?  Does rails3 not follow the restful style any more?  Or have a made a mistake which doesn't follow REST?

Answer (score 0):

```
match '/dashboard', :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'index'
```

Perhaps? I've not tested this though.